# How to run python files kept in separate folders from a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker

i have a dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch

ENV PIP pip

RUN \
    $PIP install --upgrade pip && \
    $PIP install scikit-learn && \
    $PIP install scikit-image && \
    $PIP install rasterio && \  
    $PIP install geopandas && \ 
    $PIP install matplotlib

COPY sentools sentools
COPY data data
COPY vegetation.py .
```

Now in my project i have two python files vegetation and forest. i have kept each of them in  separate folders. How can i create separate docker images for both python files and execute the containers for them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the base code is same, and only the container is supposed to run up with different Python Script, So then I will suggest using single Docker and you will not worry about the management of two docker image.

Set `vegetation.py` to default, when container is up without passing ENV it will run `vegetation.py` and if the ENV `FILE_TO_RUN` override during run time, the specified file will be run.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9 
ENV FILE_TO_RUN="/vegetation.py"
COPY vegetation.py /vegetation.py
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python $FILE_TO_RUN"]
```

Now, if you want to run `forest.py` then you can just pass the path file to ENV.

```
docker run -it -e FILE_TO_RUN="/forest.py" --rm my_image
```

or

```
docker run -it -e FILE_TO_RUN="/anyfile_to_run.py" --rm my_image
```

**updated:**

You can manage with args+env in your docker image.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9 
ARG APP="default_script.py"
ENV APP=$APP
COPY $APP /$APP
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python /$APP"]
```

Now build with ARGs

```
docker build --build-arg APP="vegetation.py" -t app_vegetation .
```

or

```
docker build --build-arg APP="forest.py" -t app_forest .
```

Now good to run

```
docker run --rm -it app_forest
```

copy both

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9 
# assign some default script name to args
ARG APP="default_script.py"
ENV APP=$APP
COPY vegetation.py /vegetation.py
COPY forest.py /forest.py
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python /$APP"]
```

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use environment variables under this project but a good solution

Comment: that worked for me but what if i have to use a default python script for `ENV` in case if it is not defined at the time of build. How can i do that? In addition to all this working

Comment: added. you can assign default script name to args.

Comment: ```
# assign some default script name to args
ARG APP="default_script.py"
``` so if you missed at build, `default_script.py` will be pick

Comment: this throws up error `ARG requires exactly 1 argument`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199419/discussion-between-adiii-and-rehan).

Answer (score 2):

If you insist in creating separate images, you can always use the [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) command.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch
ARG file_to_copy
ENV PIP pip

RUN \
    $PIP install --upgrade pip && \
    $PIP install scikit-learn && \
    $PIP install scikit-image && \
    $PIP install rasterio && \  
    $PIP install geopandas && \ 
    $PIP install matplotlib

COPY sentools sentools
COPY data data
COPY $file_to_copy .
```

And the build the image like that:

```
docker build --buid-arg file_to_copy=vegetation.py .
```

or like that

```
docker build --buid-arg file_to_copy=forest.py .
```

Comment: it builds the image but it's not executing my scripts. says that executable file not found in path. How can i execute kit?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a Docker container, you can specify what command to run at the end of the `docker run` command.  So you can build a single image that contains both scripts and pick which one runs when you start the container.

The scripts should be "normally" executable: they need to have the executable permission bit set, and they need to start with a line like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and you should be able to *locally* (outside of Docker) run

```sh
. some_virtual_environment/bin/activate
./vegetation.py
```

Once you've gotten through this, you can copy the content into a Docker image

```sh
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY sentools sentools
COPY data data
COPY vegetation.py forest.py .
CMD ["./vegetation.py"]
```

Then you can build and run this image with either script.

```sh
docker build -t trees .
docker run --rm trees ./vegetation.py
docker run --rm trees ./forest.py
```

If you actually want this to be two separate images, you can create two separate Dockerfiles that differ only in their final `COPY` and `CMD` lines, and use the `docker build -f` option to pick which one to use.

```
$ tail -2 Dockerfile.vegetation
COPY vegetation.py ./
CMD ["./vegetation.py"]
$ docker build -t vegetation -f Dockerfile.vegetation .
$ docker run --rm vegetation
```